# change extension obfuscate XML file contents

Tags: xml, file, obfuscation

I have SlideShowPro, a Flash photo app that loads an XML file with the paths to the images.
Now I don't want people to go sniff in the XML file to get to the images.

I tried changing the file images.xml to spacer.gif and it seems to work fine.
But I would like to know if I would run into any problems changing the extension.

btw already used a few techniques to make the images not so accessible, I know there is no bulletproof solution. Obfuscating the XML file is just another trick..

Answer (score 0):

I think changing the extension is fine as long as you define a clear mine type everywhere you use it, otherwise browsers and servers might start to do guesswork based on the extension.

If you are able to modify the Flash app, you might implement a simple decoding mechanism like rot13, and save the xml encoded.

Comment: What do you mean with defining a clear mime type? On my server?
So .gif is not a good idea than as it is already defined as image/gif